# Angular 2 fullcalender show the long event in the event count for every date

Tags: jquery, html, angular, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar with `angular 2.` I want to show the event count for the particular day in the event calendar. I used some function to show the count using the `data-num` attribute coming on the `HTML tag`, but when the event is more than the one day long that event count is not coming to the other day than its start date.

my template file is looks like this:

```
<angular2-fullcalendar id="calendar" [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Below are the code I used to show the event count:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
        var cDay;
        for( cDay = view.start.clone(); cDay.isBefore(view.end) ; cDay.add(1, 'day') ){
            var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var dateNum = cDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var dayEl = $('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateNum + '"]');
            var eventCount = $('.fc-event[date-num="' + dateNum + '"]').length;
            if(eventCount){
               console.log(eventCount);
               var html = '<span class="event-count"> <i>' + eventCount + '</i> Events</span>';
                dayEl.append(html);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how it looks
[image: thats what it looks]

Comment: rather than iterating the DOM I would get the events using the clientEvents method. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/ Then you get actual event objects with start/end dates rather than DOM elements. And for each day on the calendar you can check whether the date is within the start/end dates for each event.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get data using the clientEvents method and how to check through each day?

Comment: well it looks like you already know how to check through each day - you wrote that code above in your `for` loop. Unless you're saying that doesn't work? And to use clientevents, it's simple. `var events = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents");`. `events` will be an array of all the events currently displayed on the calendar, which you can loop through.

Comment: So call that first, then start your `for` loop through all the days. Within that, do another loop through `events` and check if the current day in your loop is within the event start/end dates. If so, increment your count for that day.

Comment: ok each day i know but in the angular2 fullcalender the code you given var events = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents"); will not work as the i am not using the jquery full calender i am using the angular2 full calender

Comment: well I don't know the syntax for that, but I guess you must do, otherwise you couldn't have initialised your calendar at all. However you invoke the fullcalendar object precisely, you can still call that method on the object. And just for clarity, fullCalendar is still jQuery underneath (it can't work without it), but perhaps angular may have wrapped it up inside some other container, I don't know angular at all I'm afraid (every time I look at some angular code, it gives me a headache :-) )